# Parsing the text using lex

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

I want to a parse a text file with a specific syntax.

The contents of file would be like

```
 The Living Room is a room.
```

I have written the following tokens in lex

```
The            return THETOK;
[a-zA-Z]*      return ROOMNAME;
"is a room."   return ISROOMTOK;
```

And in the yacc file I have written the following

```
  command: THETOK ROOMNAME ISROOMTOK
          {
              printf($2);
          }
```

This is working for the text like

```
   The kitchen is a room.
```

But not working for

```
   The Living Room is a room.
```

Thanks in Advance. #TIA

Comment: *yacc* does the parsing. *lex* does the lexical analysis. Be clear. Your grammar does not allow the syntax you are trying to use, and your lexer does my have any rule that would recognise 'Living'.

Comment: It need not be only Living it can be any name like kitchen , hall , bedroom etc. The syntax is like :  The <RoomName> is a room. Need to implement in  such a way that <RoomName> can have spaces.

Comment: I would need a more rigorous specification than that.

Comment: The syntax of the commands will be like : The <RoomName> is a room.I should be able to identify the room name. Now with the above code i am able to parse The Kitchen is a room. because Kitchen is a single word but when I give The Living Room is a room. it is saying syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z ]*      return ROOMNAME;
```

will match spaces into your token `ROOMNAME`.  (But it will also match your entire input string, except for the period.)

However, I wonder whether there is more to your lex spec than you have shown, since I don't follow how the spaces between "The" and "kitchen" and "kitchen" and "is" are being dealt with.  Are spaces being consumed elsewhere?  Are they discarded by the default pattern?